# .Net Connecting to Sonic MQ

Tags: java, c#, jms

OK, honestly, I have no idea on this one...

I've been asked to write a application that subscribes to published topics from an external Sonic MQ

The only thing I have to go on is a Java Test Client, which works, it doesn't do anything apart from displaying the message in a text box... and we only have the compiled JAR files, no source.

I did also find another example which has a suite of Sonic assemblies, https://sourceforge.net/projects/sonicmq-cs-jms/ but this only deals with sending and receiving from queues... whereas I need to SUBSCRIBE to published Topics.

Many googles have been carried out but I cannot seem to find the right answer or possibly ask the right question.

Any guidance (or samples) gratefully accepted

Comment: You could always try and decompile the Java classes for a closer look. IntelliJ has a build-in decompiler, but there are several (free) standalone decompilers out there, if you want to go down this route.

Comment: That is one plan ...

Comment: https://community.progress.com/community_groups/technology_partner/w/technologypartner/283.progress-sonicmq-v7-6-net-client-guide

Comment: There is a chapter on publish subscribe messaging.